# Application Error while deploying flask app to Azure

Tags: flask, azure-web-app-service, application-error

I am trying to deploy flask based app to Azure. The app is working fine locally but I get Application error on Azure.

I checked the docker logs and found that container does'nt respond to the port.
I have tried changing port by configuring WEBSITE_PORT, still same issue.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guAnO.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You need to include a bit more information.  As in how you're setting up the flask app.   How it's deployed.

Comment: This is due to the Azure Web App's limitation of only supporting port 80 and 443.

Comment: which port no. u have added in WEBSITE_PORT ?